# Why am I unable to interact with an element after assigning an ID with JQuery attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Actual Code]

[image: Chrome Inspect view]

The images show the id `#fire-image` being assigned to the `<img>` element that is created on line 3.

The next block starting line 6 is just a console log to recognize the image has been clicked.

With the Chrome inspect tool it does say the `<img>` element has an ID of `#fire-image` however when that image is clicked in the browser it doesn't recognize the click and log "Fire clicked..." to the console.

Why am I not able to interact with the image even though the browser recognizes it as having the correct ID?

Comment: id values should not be re-used within the same page. They're the unique identifier for the element.

Comment: as @Pointy has said. try to give another id for the span element

Comment: Please read [ask], and please **do not post images of code**.  Post the actual code itself so people can copy / paste.  Better yet, create an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning an event to whatever the query `$("#fire-image")` returns.

Well, at first there is no such element because you add this ID at a later point in time. Therefore, the event is not bound to any element at all, and thus will never be triggered.

One solution is to add the event to a parent element which you do know exists, for instance as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '#fire-image', function() {/* your code */});
```

Check out [jQuery `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information. (Notice that in practice, you may want to bind this event to some more immediate parent.)

Another solution is to bind the event to `$("#fire-image")` only *after* you assign it its ID.

EDIT:
I noticed that you are also repeating IDs in your HTML elements. This you should [avoid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score 1):

The element doesn't exist when you're attempting to add the listener. You need to add it to a parent element and then use the selector argument. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#fire-image', function () {
    // Do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The second listener (`console.log("Fire clicked...")`) is overriding the first listener. You should add a variable to check whether it's `#fire-image` has been clicked or not:

```
var fireClicked = false;
$("#fire-image").on("click", () => {
    if (!fireClicked) {
        console.log("Making fire...");
        $(this).clone().add("<img />").attr("src", "assets/fire-icon.png").attr("id", "fire-image").css("position", "absolute").height(200); //Because you posted an image, you'll have to fill the rest of this in yourself.
        fireClicked = true;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Fire clicked...");
    }
})
```